# wallpaper/background switches back to default when in dark mode 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, 22.04

After upgrading to 22.04, I realized that the wallpaper/background will switch back to default jammy wallpaper when in dark model even after removing and setting it to solid color. This problem doesn't appear while in light mode. I think this is a Gnome related issue?

command line used; 
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'`

Kindly advise

**update** 
as suggested by @vanadium(thank you), it's the new feature in 22.04. and adding -dark will enable the change. Hence, for those wanting to have a solid black ground without using a wallpaper, just use this command in terminal

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark ''`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a problem. It is by design. It is a new feature in Ubuntu 22.04.

While in dark mode, set your other background again. That will stick.

With gsettings, the background for the dark theme is set in a different key, `picture-uri-dark` under `org.gnome.desktop.background`.

The rationale is that one may want two variants of a background, one that goes better with the light theme, and one that could go better with the dark theme. Not all backgrounds go equally well with a light or dark theme. This way, you are in charge. You can set one background that goes with the light theme, another that goes with the dark theme, and the system will automatically switch the backgrounds as well when you move from the light to the dark theme.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I actually ran those two commands while in dark mode and nothing happened.

Comment: No offense to anyone, but that is dumb. It broke so many wallpaper apps.