# How to change desktop background from command line in Wayland?

Tags: command-line, wayland, desktop-background, 22.04

What is the command to change the desktop background from the command line in Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a separate key for dark mode now for 22.04. You can read it  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403952/wallpaper-background-switches-back-to-default-when-in-dark-mode-22-04-lts) in vanadium's answer

To set the wallpaper of the light mode:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ''
```

To set the wallpaper of the dark mode:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark ''
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that was a difference for dark mode. Now I see why it did work as I use dark mode.