# Splashy wallpaper not working in ubuntu 22.04 dark mode

Tags: 20.04, gnome, display, desktop-background, mode

I installed Splashy wallpaper in Ubuntu 22.04 and for light mode it works really fine but whenever I change to dark mode it switches back to the default jellyfish wallpaper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find your answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403952/wallpaper-background-switches-back-to-default-when-in-dark-mode-22-04-lts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wallpaper/background switches back to default when in dark mode 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403952/wallpaper-background-switches-back-to-default-when-in-dark-mode-22-04-lts)