# Ubuntu 22.04 background color and wallpaper not showing together

Tags: gnome, themes, desktop-background

In 20.04 I can choose a background color and center a wallpaper image for a nice effect.

In 22.04 I seem to be able to choose either a color or wallpaper, but not both.

Does anyone know how I can choose a color and a centered wallpaper image at the same time?

I can't imagine Ubuntu would force everyone to have black backgrounds around centered wallpaper images. (I'm using a dark theme).

[I can get this in 20.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tKzs.jpg)

[This is all I can get in 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBSSt.jpg)

Comment: it's the new feature for 22.04, you can find the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403952/wallpaper-background-switches-back-to-default-when-in-dark-mode-22-04-lts)

Comment: could you post a sample of the effect you are looking to get? I just tried with Tweaks and the Centered option in Appearance under Backgrounds still does the job.

Comment: Yeah, i used the command line to change the background color(which is black) and i'm in dark mode

Comment: I went into dcongf and manually try several combinations and find that when choosing a centered wallpaper, the background will automatically changes to black regardless of light or dark mode (x11 and wayland). However, i don't see any error messages from the log. Hence, i'm not sure whether this a 22.04 fixed preset or bug. Sorry, I wasn't able to point you to the right direction.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon Thanks for checking for me. I'm sure it's a bug, since the options for colors are there but the colors don't show up behind an image that doesn't fill the desktop. Do you know where I should actually report a bug for ubuntu 22.04 issues like this? Thanks.

Comment: you can file the bug at [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/). And you can find instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to do this also. Has there been a fix yet? I have an image I'd like to center, in my case it's the color #16171f *and* I'd like to set the background to #16171f as well. At the momment I have an image with the color of #16171f and a background color of #000000 even though I set the background color (in dconf) to #16171f

Comment: Great question, I'm still having the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04.3.  The suggested answer below and the response to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403952/wallpaper-background-switches-back-to-default-when-in-dark-mode-22-04-lts do not resolve the concern.

Answer (score 4):

On 22.04 what finally helped set the background from a picture to a solid colour was:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
```

(This seems to be a new setting)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I can get a picture or a background color, but not both. I want both.